# Test data for repeat sales indices

Tags: data-request, housing

I'm interested in calculating a repeat sales index like that of [Case and Shiller (1987)](http://www.nber.org/papers/w2393) or  [Bailey, Muth and Nourse (1963)](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1963.10480679). While I believe I have a handle on the econometrics, to test my implementation I need two things:

1. Data with repeat sales transactions (e.g. real estate or art)
2. A price index based on repeat sales calculated off of the data in (1)

Thus far, I've been able to find many examples of repeat sales indices ([FHFA](http://www.fhfa.gov/DataTools/Downloads/Pages/House-Price-Index.aspx), [CoreLogic Case–Shiller Indexes](http://www.corelogic.com/products/corelogic-case-shiller.aspx), [Mei Moses art indices](http://www.artasanasset.com/main/computation.php), [Herengracht Index](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1540-6229.00711/abstract)). Unfortunately, none with the underlying data used to construct the index.

I don't need to be able to fully recreate an existing index. I'm just looking for a set of data and index values to verify that my implementation is correct. In the event that the data (1) but not a calculated index (2) is available, that would be useful, but only if the data is clean and organized enough that I can focus primarily on the implementation rather than data issues.

Comment: What happened to your brilliant answer in [my question](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9774/pricing-a-european-call-option-while-absence-of-arbitrage-is-violated)? Did you delete it, or was it deleted? :O

Comment: I thought maybe I misunderstood some of your notation and made a mistake with my answer.

Comment: Only the last part was a mistake, I think. The rest was brilliant, iirc